# How to find the values of a and b?

Tags: polynomials, cubics

If the polynomial 6x<sup>4</sup> + 8x<sup>3</sup> - 5x<sup>2</sup> + ax + b is exactly divisible by the polynomial 2x<sup>2</sup> - 5, then find the values of a and b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Long divide then equate the remainder to $\,0\,$ to get equations for $\,a,b.$

Comment: I did try long division, but it doesn't give the remainder as zero, I get the remainder as ax + 20x + b + 25.

Comment: Did you equate to $\,0\,$ both coefs of the linear remainder? Solving those equations yields the values of $\,a,b\,$ that makes the remainder zero.

Comment: can you just do it and show us pls...

Comment: $(a\!+\!20)\,x + b\!+\!25\,$ is the zero polynomial iff all coefs $= 0,\,$ i.e. $\,a+20 = 0 = b+25.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

The roots of $2x^2-5$ must be roots of our polynomial:

$$\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{c}
6\cdot\frac{25}4+15\sqrt{\frac52}-\frac{25}2+\sqrt{\frac52}a+b=0\\
\phantom{1}\\
6\cdot\frac{25}4-15\sqrt{\frac52}-\frac{25}2-\sqrt{\frac52}a+b=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Adding up the equations you get

$$50+2b=0$$

And substracting them:

$$30\sqrt{\frac52}+2\sqrt{\frac52}a=0$$

So $a=-15$, $b=-25$.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write $$6x^4 + 8x^3 - 5x^2 + ax + b=(2x^2-5)(Ax^2+Bx+C)$$ Expand the rhs to get $$6x^4 + 8x^3 - 5x^2 + ax + b=2Ax^4+2Bx^3+(2C-5A)x^2-5Bx-5C$$ Now identify the coefficients of the differents powers of $x$. Using $x^4,x^3,x^2$, this leads to $A=3$, $B=4$,$C=5$.

I am sure that you can take from here.